# How to export from Mingle to TFS 2010 (Scrum for Team System)

Tags: tfs, scrum, teamsystem

We've currently got all our User Stories and Tasks in Thoughtworks Mingle, but what to move them into TFS 2010 which we're be using with Scrum For Team System.

Has anyone had any experience doing this?  If so, how did you go about doing it?  Were there any gotchas along the way?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Mingle, so I'm not sure what kind of access you have to the data.  I can envision two scenarios:

*1.  API Access to Mingle data

If this is the case, it's going to be very simple to create the new work items programmatically.  We do this today between our help-desk system and TFS.  It's just a matter of creating a work item, setting the fields, and calling "Save()".

*2.  Export access to Mingle data

This is probably an easier solution.  Export to Excel (via CSV or custom conversion), and create a TFS list in Excel using the plug-in.  Reorder your columns as necessary in the exported data, and copy and paste from the exported data to the TFS data.  Click on "Publish" and you're done.

Between the two, I'd recommend the API approach if this is going to be ongoing.  If it's going to be a one-time thing, the Excel approach works fine.

Comment: In mingle we have hierarchical relationships like Epic Story --> Story --> Task how would that translate across into TFS?

Comment: I'd go the code route to migrate these.  TFS 2010 supports hierarchical work items, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: How does the export to excel in Mingle work with the hierarchy.  Excel supports the TFS Hierarchy and you could likely still pull this in via Excel if Mingle can export the hierarchy in the way Excel consumes/displays the hierarchy.

Comment: I haven't played enough with the hierarchy within Excel.  I would guess that you would need to do a decent amount of manipulation of the source data, particularly because your TFS work item numbers would be generated on publish.  Excel could still be an option here, for sure, though.  I continue to be impressed with the TFS/Excel integration.

Comment: Ok, I'll check and get back to you :)

Comment: Ok, I think we've got it working using a slightly hand crafted export from Mingle.  Thanks for the advice guys!

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm in exactly the same situation - I need to sync between mingle and TFS 2012.